# Error JBPM MySQL HornetQ Human-task-service

Tags: mysql, jbpm, hornetq

I changed my database to mysql, when I run the the demo process I get this error:

[main] ERROR service.hornetq.HornetQTaskClientConnector.connect  - Unable to connect to server using configuration org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory?port=5445&host=127-0-0-1

but i configured all the XML files cleanly like the tutorial:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.3/userguide/ch.installer.html

thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your HornetQ acceptor. YOu probably have a different IP on the Acceptor.

Comment: i downloaded the jbpm-installer(5.3.O) and when i run the demo process with the default configuration the problem disappear. But if i use MySQL i heve this error (the DB was exported cleanly but i don't run the demo process) i changed the hornetq configuration on web.xml ( $home\task-service\resources\war)  like this
      <init-param>
       <param-name>hornetq.host</param-name>
       <param-value>127.0.0.1</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
       <param-name>hornetq.port</param-name>
       <param-value>5445</param-value>
      </init-param> BUT NO RESULT

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the jbpm-installer(5.3.O) and when i run the demo process with the default configuration the problem disappear. But if i use MySQL i heve this error (the DB was exported cleanly but i don't run the demo process) i changed the hornetq configuration on web.xml ( $home\task-service\resources\war) like this  hornetq.host 127.0.0.1   hornetq.port 5445  BUT NO RESULT